# How to open GIT bash and give clone commands using batch file

Tags: git, batch-file, github, git-bash, git-shell

```
Start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login 
cd E:
git clone SshLink
```

The above command is first opening normal `cmd` and then `E:` drive and then `gitbash` shell. I just want to open `git-shell` directly and change the directory to `E:` drive and give `clone` command.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "cd /e; git clone SshLink; bash"
```

That will open a bash, go to the drive E and try the `git clone`
The final `bash` allows for the session to not close immediately.

---

Other option, as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307990/how-to-open-git-bash-and-give-clone-commands-using-batch-file/61308196?noredirect=1#comment108457829_61308196) by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo):

```
Start /d E:\ "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "git clone SshLink; bash"
```

That would use the [`/d` option of `start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start).

Comment: It would make more sense, to use the available `start` options, i.e. `/D`. For example, `Start /D E:\ "%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" -C "git …`. _The `/D` option allows to preset the working directory._

Comment: @Compo Thank you, good point. I have edited the answer accordingly to include your comment.